# Take row of a dataframe that add up to a given value

Tags: python, dataframe, optimization

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

For which a have to take users, from the id column, untill the total value add up to a given value, **14** for example. How can I chose the rows to satisfy this condition in an effitient way?

This is the data I'm using for the example:

```
{'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10},
 'valor': {0: 5.690813772729765,
  1: 5.502473982705203,
  2: 7.341171631905721,
  3: 6.792634352953639,
  4: 3.3972025109972535,
  5: 3.417867922325758,
  6: 7.336228970419381,
  7: 0.048008919685266216,
  8: 2.365638019103776,
  9: 0.9593678139592221}}
```

Comment: Anything that you've tried, which didn't work?

Comment: I'm traying this with loops, but I'm not sure how to test all the cases and even then it is taking for ever to run.

Comment: Does it have to be exactly 14?

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez you should add the try in the question.

Comment: @Nathan The closest  one "<="

Comment: If you need 'the closest one', you'd have to check every single possibility, which is 2**10 in your example (still doable), but in larger databases this is going to take forever... Why exactly do you need to do this?

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez - what is expected output?

Comment: Will the ids always start from 1 and cover every single value until the maximum?

Comment: @jezrael It is basically a Knapsack Problem, I need to optimaze space.

Comment: @Nathan The ids can vary from range.

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez - Then it is really complicated, I think [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/150677/158336) should help.

Comment: Do you only need the closest value, or also the corresponding id's?

Comment: @Nathan I need the id as well

Comment: My current answer also supplies the ids as a string

Answer (score 2):

You can find the closest value using:

```
def options(valor, i, total, maximum, lowest, lst_ids):
    if total > maximum:
        return total, lst_ids
    ids = ''
    for j in range(i, len(valor)):
        lst_ids += ', ' + str(valor[j][1])
        new_score, new_ids = options(valor, j + 1, total + valor[j][0], maximum, lowest, lst_ids)
        lst_ids = lst_ids.replace(', ' + str(valor[j][1]), '')
        if new_score < lowest:
            lowest = new_score
            ids = new_ids
    return lowest, ids


data = {'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10},
        'valor': {0: 5.690813772729765, 1: 5.502473982705203, 2: 7.341171631905721, 3: 6.792634352953639,
                  4: 3.3972025109972535, 5: 3.417867922325758, 6: 7.336228970419381, 7: 0.048008919685266216,
                  8: 2.365638019103776, 9: 0.9593678139592221}}

valor = [(data['valor'][i], data['id'][i]) for i in data['valor']]
closest_score, ids = options(valor, 0, 0, 14, 1e10, '')
ids = ids[2:]
print(closest_score, ids)
```

This returns `14.034419476793634 1, 7, 8, 10`, the first part is the lowest value, the second part is the ids required to get this score. If you want to get the actual numbers as integers you can just use:

```
ids = [int(i) for i in ids.split(', ')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **brute-force** solution using a generator with `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
from operator import itemgetter

d = dict(zip(d['id'].values(), d['valor'].values()))  # restructure dictionary

def gen_ids_sum(d):
    for id_tup in chain.from_iterable(combinations(d, i) for i in range(1, len(d))):
        yield id_tup, sum(map(d.__getitem__, id_tup))

ids, val_sum = min(gen_ids_sum(d), key=lambda x: (x[1] <= 14, abs(x[1] - 14)))

print(ids, val_sum)

(1, 7, 8, 10) 14.034419476793634
```

**Setup**

```
d = {'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10},
     'valor': {0: 5.690813772729765, 1: 5.502473982705203, 2: 7.341171631905721,
               3: 6.792634352953639, 4: 3.3972025109972535, 5: 3.417867922325758,
               6: 7.336228970419381, 7: 0.048008919685266216, 8: 2.365638019103776,
               9: 0.9593678139592221}}
```